# Home screen is moving about in iOS7

Tags: ios

I successfully downloaded and activated the new iOS 7, but now my screen won't stop shaking. It looks like my iPhone 5 is caught in the middle of a hurricane. Is there anything I can do to make it stop?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s38g6F6NgEE here's an example of your problem, I have the same thing but mine's a 4 and I don't think I have paralax, any ideas?

Comment: Hyperbole is sometimes effective, but let's be clear. If you placed your phone on a stationary table, the home screen would be rock solid and this animation effect is due to accelerometer input, correct?

Answer (score 8):

There are one of three things going on here.  I'm not sure which is most likely.

1. You have long-pressed an app icon and entered into the move/delete mode where you can adjust locations and remove apps.  To get out of this, click home.
2. You are experiencing the parallax effect of the home screen.  You can turn this off in `Settings>General>Accessibility>Reduce Motion *On*`
3. You are trying to be funny.  Stop that.

Comment: I followed no.2 and my phone is back to normal. Thank you! Big sigh of relief...

Comment: I imagine some people with epilepsy or dyslexia or other nausea inducing problems like vertigo might find it very disconcerting indeed.  Wonder when the first scare story gets published resulting in them having to use a warning when it's turned on...

Comment: My biggest wish is game developers start reading that **Reduce Motion** flag and cut down on some of the cutesy animation in their games.